# Should I use 'volatile' together with '__block' qualifier when a block is executed on another thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, volatile

Let's look at this piece of code:

```
- (void)addOperationAndWait:(void (^)())operation {
  __block NSException *exception = nil;
  [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    @try {
      operation();
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {
      exception = ex;
    }
  }];
  [self.queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
  if (exception) {
    @throw exception;
  }
}
```

These lines of code are executed on a one thread:

```
 __block NSException *exception = nil;

  if (exception) {
    @throw exception;
  }
```

and this line of code are executed on another thread:

```
exception = ex;
```

So should I declare the `exception` variable as `volatile` to be sure that a value of the variable is not cached by the threads using it?

I have a doubt because of this piece of documentation:

*Volatile variables apply another type of memory constraint to individual variables. The compiler often optimizes code by loading the values for variables into registers. For local variables, this is usually not a problem. If the variable is visible from another thread however, such an optimization might prevent the other thread from noticing any changes to it. Applying the volatile keyword to a variable forces the compiler to load that variable from memory each time it is used. You might declare a variable as volatile if its value could be changed at any time by an external source that the compiler may not be able to detect*

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

Comment: I'd recommend you figure out why exceptions are thrown at all. The Objective-C rule is that exceptions should only thrown to indicate programming errors. You don't catch them, you fix the code.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for your reply. But exception is not the most important thing here. This is only a clear example. I have a few similar situation is my code and I wonder if the code like this - without `volatile` qualifier - is fully reliable.

Answer (score 1):

volatile doesn't help for multi-threaded access to a variable *at all*. Use atomic operations, or use an atomic property.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` is used when the variable can be changed by things the compiler cannot see. Here, everything happening is seen by the compiler.